# How to freeze systemctl service - prevent a restart

Tags: systemctl

We have a service with systemctl that's restarted with:

```
systemctl restart backend.service
```

nothing crazy. However as part of our automated infrastructure code, this command gets called, even when want the service to be stopped. So we need some way to permanently stop the service, until we want to bring it back online. Is there some command like this:

```
systemctl stop backend.service
systemctl freeze backend.service  # ?
```

I am looking for some command that can stop the service and prevent a restart until further notice.

Comment: systemctl disable backend.service

Comment: yes but `systemctl restart backend.service` will relaunch it from what I can tell

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `systemctl mask [unit]` may be what you're looking for. Quoting [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#mask%20UNIT%E2%80%A6):

> `mask UNIT…`
>
> Mask one or more units, as specified on the command line. This will link these unit files to `/dev/null`, making it impossible to start them. This is a stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual activation. Use this option with care. This honors the `--runtime` option to only mask temporarily until the next reboot of the system. The `--now` option may be used to ensure that the units are also stopped. This command expects valid unit names only, it does not accept unit file paths.